# Error in reshaping input tokenized text predicting the sentiments in a lstm rnn

Tags: keras, lstm, sentiment-analysis, recurrent-neural-network, text-analysis

I am new to neural network and have been learning it's application in the field of text analytics, so i have used a lstm rnn for the application in python.

After training the model on a dataset of dimension 20,000*1 (2000-being the text and ,1-being the sentiment of the text) i got a good accuracy of 99%, after which i validated the model which was working fine(using the model.predict()function).

Now just to test my model i have been trying to give random text inputs either from a dataframe or variables containing some text but i always landup with the error of reshaping the array , where it is required that the input to the rnn model be of the dimension (1,30).

But when i re-input the training data into the model for prediction , the model works absolutely fine , why is this happening?

[link for the screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yv7r2.jpg)

[image]

[link for image of model summary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OusDm.jpg)

[image]

[training data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHG42.jpg)

[image]

I am just stuck here and any kind of suggestion  will help me learning more about rnn, i am attaching the error and the rnn model code with this request.

Thank You

Regards

Tushar Upadhyay

```
    import numpy as np 
    import pandas as pd 
    import keras
    import sklearn

    from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
    from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
    from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
    from keras.models import Sequential
    from keras.layers import Dense, Embedding, LSTM
     from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
    from keras.utils.np_utils import to_categorical
    import re


    data=pd.read_csv('..../twitter_tushar_data.csv')
    max_fatures = 4000
    tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=max_fatures, split=' ')
    tokenizer.fit_on_texts(data['tweetText'].values)
    X = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(data['tweetText'].values)
    X = pad_sequences(X)


    embed_dim = 128
    lstm_out = 196
    model = Sequential()
    keras.layers.core.SpatialDropout1D(0.2) #used to avoid overfitting
    model.add(Embedding(max_fatures, embed_dim,input_length = X.shape[1]))
    model.add(LSTM(196, recurrent_dropout=0.2, dropout=0.2))
   model.add(Dense(2,activation='softmax'))
   model.compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam',metrics 
   = ['accuracy'])
   print(model.summary())
   #splitting data in training and testing parts

   Y = pd.get_dummies(data['SA']).values
   X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X,Y, test_size = 
   0.30, random_state = 42)
   print(X_train.shape,Y_train.shape)
   print(X_test.shape,Y_test.shape)
   batch_size = 128
   model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs = 7, batch_size=batch_size, verbose = 
   2)


   validation_size = 3500

   X_validate = X_test[-validation_size:]
   Y_validate = Y_test[-validation_size:]
   X_test = X_test[:-validation_size]
   Y_test = Y_test[:-validation_size]
   score,acc = model.evaluate(X_test, Y_test, verbose = 2, batch_size = 128)
   print("score: %.2f" % (score))
   print("acc: %.2f" % (acc))


   pos_cnt, neg_cnt, pos_correct, neg_correct = 0, 0, 0, 0
   for x in range(len(X_validate)):
   result = 
 model.predict(X_validate[x].reshape(1,X_test.shape[1]),batch_size=1,verbose 
 = 2)[0]
 if np.argmax(result) == np.argmax(Y_validate[x]):
    if np.argmax(Y_validate[x]) == 0:
        neg_correct += 1
    else:
        pos_correct += 1

if np.argmax(Y_validate[x]) == 0:
    neg_cnt += 1
else:
    pos_cnt += 1
print("pos_acc", pos_correct/pos_cnt*100, "%")
print("neg_acc", neg_correct/neg_cnt*100, "%")
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution to my question, it was just a matter of tokenizing the input properly, Thanks !! The code is below for prediction of different user inputs..

```
 text=np.array(['you are a pathetic awful movie'])
 print(text.shape)
 tk=Tokenizer(num_words=4000,lower=True,split=" ")
 tk.fit_on_texts(text)

prediction=model.predict(sequence.pad_sequences(tk.texts_to_sequences(text),
maxlen=max_review_length))
print(prediction)
print(np.argmax(prediction))
```